# Fabric Composer bna build errors

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Since moving to v0.10.x, which removed use of 'bnabuild', I'm having trouble trying to build my bna locally using 'npm install'. I'm running HLF V1.0, node v6.9.5, and npm v3.10.10. There's likely something wrong in the model that has changed since moving to v0.10.x but I cannot figure out what it is from the sparse log information. I've added the model file and js to an empty playground, but no errors are uncovered. I even tried opening directory and file permissions.

Error is:

"npm ERR! argv "/Users/guyho/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin/node" "/Users/guyho/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! petchain-network@0.0.10 prepublish: `mkdirp ./dist && composer archive create  --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/petchain-network.bna`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the petchain-network@0.0.10 prepublish script 'mkdirp ./dist && composer archive create  --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/petchain-network.bna'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the petchain-network package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mkdirp ./dist && composer archive create  --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/petchain-network.bna"

Comment: in the directory where you ran npm install, could you create the dist directory then run the command to build the archive manually 
composer archive create  --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/petchain-network.bna
and post the errors returned.

Comment: would also now recommend you install Composer v0.11.1.

Comment: I'm running composer 0.11.1. The problem continues to be lacking problem solving information.

Comment: @david_k - thanks that helped me uncover the problem. By running that command stand-alone I saw the error was in resolving the namespace within the acl. Still I thought it looked okay. I had to take a look at a current example in v0.11.1 and noticed that in the acl when granting access to all resources in entire namespace they are adding ".*" at the end. Not sure why all of a sudden that's important, but my adding this into my acl permitted it to successfully create the archive. :)